# Rows to Columns in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, cursor, sql-server-2000, pivot

I have this..

```
IDProspecto | IDObservacionCustomer | Observacion
---------------------------------------------------------    
  2204078   | 275214                | 03/9 Hable con Claudia me informa que Roberto ya se termino le deje..
  2204078   | 294567                | 19/09 SOLICITAN LLAME MAÑANA A ALEJANDRO   
  2204078   | 295310                | 20/09 se envia mail a adrian 
  2204078   | 304102                | CIA SOLICITA NO INSTALE EQUIPO
```

And I want to have this...

```
idprospecto | observacion1            | observacion2            | observacion3      | observacion4 | observacionN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  2204078   | 03/09 Hable con clau... | 19/09 solicitan llame... | 20/09 se envia... | CIA solicita..   | ...
```

I read a lot about this but I found it hard to implement, since I never used cursor and pivot is not available in SQL Server 2000, I hope someone here can help me, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since SQL Server 2000 does not have the `PIVOT` function, you should be able to use something similar to the following:

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE   @rowCount as int
DECLARE   @pivotCount as int
DECLARE   @pivotRow as varchar(10)

set @rowCount = 1
set @pivotRow = ''

create table #colsPivot
(
  id int IDENTITY(1,1),
  name varchar(20),
  CustId int
)

insert into #colsPivot
select 'Observacion', IDObservacionCustomer
from yourtable

set @pivotCount= (select COUNT(*) from #colsPivot) 

-- reset rowcount
set @rowCount = 1
set @query = ''

---- create the CASE string
while @rowCount <= @pivotCount
    begin
        set @pivotRow = (select Top 1 CustId from #colsPivot)

        set @query = @query + ', max(case when IDObservacionCustomer = ''' + @pivotRow + ''' then Observacion end) as ''Observacion_' + cast(@rowCount as varchar(10)) + ''''

        delete from #colsPivot where CustId = @pivotRow

        if @rowCount <= @pivotCount
            begin
                set @rowCount = @rowCount + 1
            end
    end

-- add the rest of the SQL Statement
set @query = 'SELECT IDProspecto ' + @query + ' from yourtable group by IDProspecto'

exec(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af163/18)

Comment: @user1738734 if an answer is helpful to you, then be sure to select one as accepted via the checkmark on the left. The accepted solution helps future visitors and you will even get reputation for accepting answers.

Comment: Im having problems impleneting this solution, first, it doesnt drop #colspivot table and cannot drop it manually i dont know why im an admin, if i have to many rows doesnt work because query nvarchar limit, and finally having this result.. "Operand data type text is invalid for max operator."

Comment: @user1738734 what column has a `text` datatype?  You can `cast()` that column as a `varchar()` and then select the `max()` value.

Comment: Ok, got it, but now if i have more than one IDProspecto it creates one column for each IDProspecto and each comment..

Comment: @user1738734 if you have more than one `IDProspecto` then you should have multiple rows because they are distinct. As far as the limit, you can try to use `varchar(8000)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this example.

**Prepare data:**

```
create table tab1
(
  IDProspecto  int,
  IDObservacionCustomer int, 
  Observacion varchar(130)
)    

insert into tab1
values (2204078,275214 ,'03/9 Hable con Claudia me informa que Roberto ya se termino le deje..' )

insert into tab1
values (2204078,294567   ,'19/09 SOLICITAN LLAME MAÑANA A ALEJANDRO   ' )

insert into tab1
values (2204078,295310 ,'20/09 se envia mail a adrian' )

insert into tab1
values (2204078,304102 ,'CIA SOLICITA NO INSTALE EQUIPO' )
```

We need `identity` field, so I create new table, and copy data from tab1.

```
create table tab2
(
  id int identity,  
  IDProspecto  int,
  IDObservacionCustomer int, 
  Observacion varchar(130)
)

insert into tab2(IDProspecto,IDObservacionCustomer,Observacion)
select IDProspecto,IDObservacionCustomer,Observacion from tab1
```

**Run query:**

```
declare @max int, @inc int, @SqlSel varchar(2000),@SqlJoin varchar(2000), @Sql varchar(2000)

select @max = max(cnt) from (
select count(1) as cnt
  from tab1
) T

select @inc = 1
select @SqlSel = 'select distinct t.IDProspecto '
select @SqlJoin = 'from tab2 t'
while @max>=@inc
begin
  select @SqlSel= @SqlSel+', tab2'+convert(varchar,@inc)+'.Observacion as o'+convert(varchar,@inc)
  select @SqlJoin = @SqlJoin+' left join tab2 as tab2'+convert(varchar,@inc)+' on t.IDProspecto = tab2'+convert(varchar,@inc)+'.IDProspecto and  tab2'+convert(varchar,@inc)+'.id='+convert(varchar,@inc)
  select @inc=@inc+1
end

select @SqlSel, @SqlJoin

exec( @SqlSel+' '+ @SqlJoin)
```

Comment: Having same problem, limited by varchar, i have to query lot of IDProspecto, and if i have more than one IDProspecto it creates lot of columns for each comment on each IDProspecto.

Comment: @user1738734 Result are fine for me. If query was too big, you can use try `insert into tab2(...) select ...from tab1 where IDProspecto betwean 1 and 10000` next time `insert into tab2(...) select ...from tab1 where IDProspecto betwean 10000 and 100000` and so on.