# Dynamic crosstab in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, dynamic-sql, crosstab

I have a table with data that looks like this:

```
pageno  groupid
100100  mpadilla
100101  Mine
105101  swachman
100100  swachman
105101  Mine
107101  mpadilla
```

I want the data to look like this (crosstab/pivot) in SQL Server 2000 (no `PIVOT` available in SQL Server 2000):

```
pageno  Mine    mpadilla        swachman
100100  --          X           X
100101  X           --          --
105101  X           --          X
107101  --          X           --
```

Here is my static solution based on this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172756.aspx.:

```
SELECT pageno, 
    [Mine] = MAX(CASE groupid WHEN 'Mine' THEN 'X' ELSE '--' END),
    [mpadilla] = MAX(CASE groupid WHEN 'mpadilla' THEN 'X' ELSE '--' END),
    [swachman] = MAX(CASE groupid WHEN 'swachman' THEN 'X' ELSE '--' END)
FROM #DistinctPages
GROUP BY pageno
ORDER BY pageno
```

What I need is a dynamic crosstab solution for SQL Server 2000. I tried adapting this to my situation but I'm just not getting it: [Rows to Columns in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844109/rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2000)

Any guidance would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @a varchar(4000)
set @a = ''
select @a = @a + x
from
(select top 100 percent
',[' +groupid + ']=MAX(CASE groupid WHEN ''' +groupid+ '''  THEN ''X'' ELSE ''--'' END)' x
from #DistinctPages Group by groupid order by groupid) t

exec ('SELECT pageno' + @a + ' FROM #DistinctPages GROUP BY pageno ORDER BY pageno')
```

Comment: @user2766661 made a small change, try again

Comment: I get incorrect syntax near ELSE. It appears that the 3 single quotes leave the -- as a comment instead of part of the statement. How do I correct that? When I remove some of the matching single quotes I get the same result.

Comment: I'm testing it again.

Comment: Ok it's getting further now. But it errors: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'Ilee'. Ilee is one of the groupids. I'm going to try and modify it to see if I can get it to run. Thank you! If I get stuck I'll ask again. If you come up with the answer to the error please let me know.

Comment: @user2766661 they are running in different scope, can't refer to the temporary table dynamicly. It can be done with a permanent table, however that can cause some other problems when other users access the table if you flush the table after the query. If you have quote in groupid it will fail. Can replace it though

Comment: I don't understand how that can be though because I have this same script modified with PIVOT of course for sql 2008 and it refers to the temp #DistinctPages table fine.

Comment: I copied your modified code including the create table part and I get the same error as I mentioned above except this time it's incorrect syntax near 'mpadilla'

Comment: I did a print @a and commented out the exec. Here's the result. Looks like there's no comma before mpadilla:     Mine=MAX(CASE groupid WHEN 'Mine'  THEN 'X' ELSE '--' END)mpadilla=MAX(CASE groupid WHEN 'mpadilla'  THEN 'X' ELSE '--' END),

Comment: I had misplaced the comma, now i used your temporary table, if it doesn't work with a temp table, try with a permanent table

Comment: Awesome work! Thank you so much! Now I have to sit and study this code so I can understand it. Thanks again.