# Dynamic pivot in SQL Server 2000 without using stored procedure or function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have these two tables:

Table A

```
    pj    item     desc        pj_id
------------------------------------
    pjA   iphone   cell phone   1
    pjA   macbook  laptop       2
    pjB   windows  os           3
```

Table B

```
     pj   item     pj_id  version   date
-----------------------------------------
     pjA  iphone     1      2       2010
     pjA  iphone     1      3       2011
     pjA  macbook    2      0       2000
     pjB  windows    3      5       2008
     pjB  windows    3      6       2014
     pjB  windows    3      7       2017
```

And I want

```
   pj    item       desc       detail1   detail2  detail3
---------------------------------------------------------
   pjA   iphone   cell phone   2010(2)   2011(3)
   pjA   macbook   laptop      2000(0)
   pjB   windows     os        2008(5)   2014(6)  2017(7)
```

You can see the column "detail" is dynamic, because there are no fix numbers of version of an item in table B

As we know, `PIVOT` or `FOR XML PATH` aren't supported on SQL Server 2000.

So I googled some solutions but they usually use stored procedure or function, but I don't have the permissions on this database.

The closest answer for me probably is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844109/rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2000?answertab=active#tab-top), but I have no idea how to use on my table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are calling SQL Server from an app language such as Java or PHP, then this requirement might be best handled there in the presentation layer.  I don't think we can do this without using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yeah that's a solution too, but I don't know how to bind two tables in a grid(I using ASP.net)

Comment: The time to upgrade from SQL Server 2000 was *years* ago.  It is not supported and has not been supported for years.

Comment: I hope at least your front end is not in Pascal or some other ancient language....

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, sometimes you don't have choice

Comment: @Hecxer . . . I can understand that for many situations.  Any organization that is using SQL Server 2000 needs to upgrade.  The application is simply not supported, and unsupported commercial software does not make for a stable environment (you can often maintain non-commercial software yourself).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. You can use a temp table to create the 'Details' with a RowNum column and then Pj_id grouped. And by using a left join, you can bring the 'Details' back in. I have only done for 3 'Details'. You can expand as you wish.

```
 declare @tableA table(pj varchar(20), item varchar(50), descb varchar(100), pj_id int)
insert into @tableA
select 'pjA', 'iphone', 'cell phone', 1 union all
select 'pjA', 'macbook', 'laptop', 2 union all
select 'pjB', 'windows', 'os', 3 

declare @tableB table(pj varchar(20), item varchar(50), pj_id int, version int,   vdate int)
insert into @tableB
select 'pjA', 'iphone', 1, 2, 2010 union all
select 'pjA', 'iphone', 1, 3, 2011 union all
select 'pjA', 'macbook', 2, 0, 2000 union all
select 'pjB', 'windows ', 3, 5, 2008 union all
select 'pjB', 'windows', 3, 6, 2014 union all
select 'pjB', 'windows',3,  7, 2017

declare @Details table(pj_id int, Detail varchar(100), RowNum int)----IDENTITY(1,1)
insert into @Details
SELECT pj_id,
        Detail=cast(vdate as varchar(20))+'('+cast(SUM(version) as varchar(20))+')',
        RowNum = (SELECT COUNT(*) ---Simulating Row_num here
                 FROM @tableB i 
                WHERE i.pj_id  = o.pj_id 
                  AND cast(i.vdate as varchar(20))<=cast(o.vdate as varchar(20))  )
   FROM @tableB  o
group  by
pj_id, cast(o.vdate as varchar(20))
  ORDER BY pj_id, Detail




select 
    A.*, 
    detail1=D1.Detail,
    detail2=D2.Detail,
    detail3=D3.Detail
from
    @tableA A

left join @Details D1 ON
    D1.pj_id=A.pj_id
    AND 
    D1.RowNum=1

left join @Details D2 ON
    D2.pj_id=A.pj_id
    AND 
    D2.RowNum=2

left join @Details D3 ON
    D3.pj_id=A.pj_id
    AND 
    D3.RowNum=3
```

I have simulated ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: It said 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name.

How could make it work on SQL 2000?

Comment: hi Hecxer, Please see the modified version. I have simulated ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: line 17

Column 'o.vdate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It works for me here, but I have modified. Please try again. I changed pj_id, cast(vdate as varchar(20)) to -> pj_id, cast(o.vdate as varchar(20))

Comment: Weird. Try SQL Server 2016 and it works, but SQL 2000 didn't

Comment: hi Hecxer, see this link where I tried to test too. http://rextester.com/VHMNM62497

Comment: Yeah I tried and it worked, as also on my SQL Server 2016, but run on SQL Server 2000 return an error said  'o.vdate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.